# How to remove an image tag in Docker without removing the image itself?

Tags: docker

Let's say I want to tag a Docker image, and make a typo. How do I remove the tag without removing the image itself? Neither the manpages nor the Docker documentation mention removing tags.

```
docker tag 0e5574283393 my-imaj
docker tag 0e5574283393 my-image
# docker untag my-imaj # There is no "docker untag"!
```

Comment: For those who want to untag `<none>`-tagged images like `foo/bar:<none>`: use `docker images --digests` and `docker rmi foo/bar@<digest>` as described at https://success.docker.com/KBase/How_to_Remove_a_Signed_Image_with_a_%3Cnone%3E_Tag

Answer (score 370, accepted):

*If your image is tagged with more than one tag*, then `docker rmi` will remove the tag, but not the image.

So in your example ...

```
# docker rmi my-imaj
```

... will remove that tag and leave the image present with the other correct tag.

Comment: Thanks. I wish they mentioned this in the documentation  :-/

Comment: goddamnit...how do I remove the image via the tag? :)

Comment: If the tag I'm removing is the last one though, the image will get removed. So I wonder what is the answer to the question in the topic? How do I remove the tag and keep the image cached?

Comment: My scenario is one image with a tag: 1) Remove the tag from the image, but keep the image cached, tagless. 2) Run `docker build` with the same tag, but possibly different `Dockerfile`. 3a) If the `Dockerfile` didn't change, the cached image is tagged back with the same tag. 3b) If the `Dockerfile` did change, the new image is tagged with the original tag and the old image will be removed using `docker image prune`.

Comment: And the answer is as always *use `--help`*, don't be lazy to read. `docker image remove --no-prune`.. in case somebody is interested.

Comment: **This is false, it simply removed my image.** Fortunately, knowing docker I was already suspicious, and created a backup before with `docker save`.

Comment: @peterh the answer clearly states `If your image is tagged with more than one tag...`, it should be updated however with the command from the comments that explains how to remove the last tag without removing the image.

Answer (score 54):

Run `docker rmi REPOSITORY:TAG` to remove the tag.

The `REPOSITORY` and `TAG` values come from `docker images` output.

For example

```
$ docker rmi my-image:0e5574283393
Untagged: my-image:0e5574283393
```

Answer (score 32):

Starting from an empty docker repo, import an image by typing:

```
#docker run hello-world
```

Run the `docker images` command to list the images. The result should look like this:

```
REPOSITORY        TAG           IMAGE ID          CREATED           SIZE
hello-world       latest        7bc42cc48a84      4 weeks ago       316MB
```

Now let's create an image tag called *v1* by running the `docker tag` command:

```
#docker tag hello-world:latest hello-world:v1
```

If we run the `docker images` command we'll see our new tag like this:

```
REPOSITORY        TAG           IMAGE ID          CREATED           SIZE
hello-world       latest        7bc42cc48a84      4 weeks ago       316MB
hello-world         v1          7bc42cc48a84      4 weeks ago       316MB
```

To delete a specific tag (to answer the original question), run the docker rmi `hello-world:v1` where *v1* is the tag name.  The output will look like this:

```
#docker rmi hello-world:v1
Untagged: hello-world:v1
```

Run the `docker images` command to list the images. Notice that the image tag has been removed:

```
REPOSITORY        TAG           IMAGE ID          CREATED           SIZE
hello-world       latest        7bc42cc48a84      4 weeks ago       316MB
```

Answer (score 1):

Tag other image with you tag name and afterwards your tag from your current image will be removed.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Please clarify or add some command example steps. Check out the guide here: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Not a useful answer, if the tag was a typo as indicated, you wouldn't want it on some other image either.

Comment: Very useful answer!